# MVC model data that is rendered in the view is null when posted back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen similar questions to this and followed the routine answer which is to ensure all model data is rendered in the HTML.

I have done that and the model is rendered in the view with @Html.HiddenFor() but when the posting back to the controller there are no items in the list ?

The view will happily render multiple items in the list, but `List<Item> Items` in the posted data is always an empty list (not null)

**Model**

```
public class ItemCollection
{
    public List<string> AvailiableActions { get; set; } 
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } 
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SelectedAction { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ItemCollection
@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "myController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.AvailiableActions)
            <table>
                @{
                    foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(s => item.Id)
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownList(item.SelectedAction, new SelectList(Model.AvailiableActions))</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }                   
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    private ActionResult myAction(ItemCollection model)
    {
        if (model.Items.Count() == 0)
        {
            // this is true.. something is wrong......
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do we need this @Html.HiddenFor(m => item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `foreach` loop to render controls for a collection. It renders duplicate `id` and `name` attributes without the necessary indexers to bind to a collection. Use a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
{ 
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Items[i].Id)
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items[i].Name)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Items[i].SelectedAction, new SelectList(Model.AvailiableActions))</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Note your view also included `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Items)` and  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => item)` which would also have failed because `item` is a complex object and you can only bind to value types. You need to remove both.

Comment: thanks very much. Working a treat. The Html.HiddenFor on the complex types was an attempt to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over all items to make sure the index is added to the generated output, you may consider using **EditorTemplates** ([an example on an other site](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)).

*EditorTemplates* allow you to specify a template for a single `Item` in `\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Item.cshtml`:

```
@model Item
@{
    var options= (List<string>)ViewData["Options"];
 }
 <tr>
     <td>
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
     </td>
     <td>@Html.DropDownList(m => m.SelectedAction, new SelectList(options))</td>
 </tr>
```

Then you may simply change your view to:

```
@model ItemCollection
@using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "myController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <table>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items, new {Options = Model.AvailiableActions })
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Where would you set the ViewData that is read from in the Editor Template ?

Comment: Actually realised its in the controller Get as soon as I wrote that :)

Comment: No, it's in the call in the main view: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items, new {Options = Model.AvailiableActions })`

Comment: Of course, the GET controller would have to populate `AvailiableAction`, but that is as it was before in your example

Comment: thanks. not knowing how to pass the List<string> stopped me from doing this before